# How to get uncommon columns in 2 tables using left joins and information_schema.columns?

Tags: sql, join, left-join

There are 2 tables which have 10 columns common in both the tables and 2 columns exist in table 2 but not in table 1. I have a task where I need to get those 2 columns present in Table 2 but not in Table 1.
The condition for the query is:

1. We must use information_schema.columns table.
2. Left join must be used on the same table information_schema.columns

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to take all the columns of Table 2 that are not in Table 1.

```
SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.tables t
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c on t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
WHERE  t.TABLE_NAME = 'table2' and c.COLUMN_NAME not in
(
   SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME
   FROM information_schema.tables t
   join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c on t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
   WHERE  t.TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
)
```

Comment: Wow! Spot on. Thanks for this. You saved me tremendous struggle at work. Thanks again.

Comment: you used not in in the query, you may recheck that and modify your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t2
    LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t1
        ON t2.COLUMN_NAME = t1.COLUMN_NAME
        AND t1.TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
WHERE t2.TABLE_NAME = 'table2'      
      AND t1.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement there care multiple solutions to this problem. Just giving a simple one:

Left join the `information_schema.columns` table with itself on the `table_name` and `column_names` and then filter out the columns of `'table1'` using `where not exists` from the joined result. Finally apply another filter on the joined result to take only the `column_name` which are in `'table2'`:

```
select isc1.column_name from information_schema.columns isc1 
    left join information_schema.columns isc2 
        on isc1.table_name = isc2.table_name and isc1.column_name = isc2.column_name
    where not exists (select column_name 
                            from information_schema.columns isc 
                                    where isc.table_name = 'table1') 
        and isc1.table_name = 'table2';
```